# Some $p$-adic congruences involving permutations

Tags: nt.number-theory, permutations, determinants, congruences, permanent

Motivated by my study of determinants and permanents, here I present several conjectures on $p$-adic congruences involving permutations.

As usual, we let $S_n$ be the symmetric group consisting of all the permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

**Conjecture 1.** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{p-1}}\prod_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}^{p-1}\frac1{j-\tau(j)}\equiv 1+(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p\tag{1}$$
and
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{p-1}}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}^{p-1}\frac1{j-\tau(j)}\equiv 2\pmod p.\tag{2}$$

**Conjecture 2.** For any prime $p$, we have
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{p-1}}\prod_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}^{p-1}\frac{j+\tau(j)}{j-\tau(j)}\equiv((p-2)!!)^2\pmod{p^2}.\tag{3}$$
If $p$ is an odd prime, then
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{p-1}}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod^{p-1}_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}\frac{j+\tau(j)}{j-\tau(j)}\equiv\frac{(-1)^{(p+1)/2}}{p-2}((p-2)!!)^2\pmod{p^2}.\tag{4}$$

**Conjecture 3.** Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv3\pmod4$.

(i) We have
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{(p-1)/2}}\prod_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}^{(p-1)/2}\frac1{j^2-\tau(j)^2}
\equiv \sum_{\tau\in S_{(p-1)/2}}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}^{(p-1)/2}\frac1{j^2-\tau(j)^2}\equiv1\pmod p.\tag{5}$$

(ii) If $p>3$, then
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{(p-1)/2}}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod^{(p-1)/2}_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}\frac{j^2+\tau(j)^2}{j^2-\tau(j)^2}\equiv0\pmod{p^2}.\tag{6}$$
When $p\equiv 7\pmod 8$, we have
$$\sum_{\tau\in S_{(p-1)/2}}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod^{(p-1)/2}_{j=1\atop \tau(j)\not=j}\frac{j^2+\tau(j)^2}{j^2-\tau(j)^2}\equiv0\pmod{p^3}.\tag{7}$$

**QUESTION.** How to prove the congruences $(1)-(7)$?

In my opinion, $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(5)$ should be relatively easy,  but the other conjectural congruences might be quite challenging.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: An empty product is regarded as $1$. Thus, $\prod_{0<j<p\atop \tau(j)\not=j}\ \ \ a_j$ is $1$ if $\tau$ is the identity of $S_{p-1}$.

Comment: Let $p$ be an odd prime,
\begin{equation*}
a_{j,k}=\begin{cases}f(j,k)&\text{if}\ j\not=k,\\\lambda&\text{if}\ j=k,\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
F(f,\lambda,n)=\det\left[a_{j,k}\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}.
\end{equation*}

We have the following

Comment: **Conjecture 1'** 
$$F(\frac{1}{j-k},\lambda,p-1) \equiv F(\frac{jk}{j-k},\lambda,p-1) \equiv \lambda^{p-1}+1\pmod{p}.
$$


Let $\lambda=1$,$$F(\frac{1}{j-k},1,p-1) \equiv 2 \pmod{p}\iff(2).$$

**Conjecture 2'** If $p>3, p\equiv3\pmod4$, then 
\begin{equation*}
F(\frac{j+k}{j-k},0,p-1)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^4}.
\end{equation*}

**Conjecture 3'** If $p\equiv3\pmod4$, then 
\begin{equation*}F(\frac{1}{j^2-k^2},\lambda,\frac{p-1}{2}) \equiv \lambda^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}
\end{equation*}

Let $\lambda=1$, $$F(\frac{1}{j^2-k^2},1,\frac{p-1}{2}) \equiv 1 \pmod{p}\iff(5)$$

Comment: **Conjecture 4'** For any odd prime $p$,
$$F(\frac{j^2+k^2}{j-k},\lambda,p-1) \equiv \lambda^{p-1}+\frac{1}{4}\pmod{p}.$$